# Angular2 RC6 pipes. Can I declare a pipe within the same .ts file as my component?

Tags: angular

Do I have to register every single pipe within @ngModule? I have one which is used by single specific component only. Would be nice to declare it right in the same file, so nothing else is aware about it.
I believe that was possible before - just can't find the right syntax.

Thank you.

Comment: As per [this change](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/4a740f23a447d7201fe655e2f016b70066752ec1) it appears that you absolutely have to use modules for this now: *“All the components and pipes now must be declarated via an NgModule. NgModule is the basic
compilation block passed into the Angular compiler […]”* – I’m not sure if there is an alternative strategy for component-private directives now…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every Pipe, Component and Directive must be declared in a Module. This is because the compiler relies on the module's declarations to parse templates. If it hasn't seen `MyPipe` in the module's declarations (or the declarations of an imported module), then it will not look for it nor recognize it when you use the pipe in the template

If it's important that no other component be able to see your Pipe, create a module that contains only the component that uses the pipe and the pipe itself, and do not export the pipe.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { MyPipe }        from './my.pipe';
import { MyComponent }   from './my.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ MyComponent, MyPipe ],
  exports:      [], // don't export what you want to keep private
  providers:    []
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since RC6, the `pipes` property has been removed from  `ComponentTypeMetadata` , you have to register them in `NgModule`.